# Asp.Net MVC Paged List and passing Search Criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I am using Troy Goode's PagedList extension on my MVC page. It is working fine by rendering the partial containing given page of records.

Now I have to implement filtering of search results. I am using AJAX form to fetch partial containing results matching with given search criteria. This works well if there are less than one page of results. If the filtered results beyond one page, there is an issue. When clicked on paging link the filtering information is gone and it results next page of unfiltered information.

What mechanism I can use to pass filtering information when something is entered to filter search results and there is paging link?

Answer (score 1):

My PagedList library takes a Func to generate the URL when you call @Html.PagedList(...):

```
page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page })
```

You simply need to customize the parameters you're passing into Url.Action (which is a Microsoft class/method, docs can be found on MSDN).

Comment: thanks @troy I will give it a try. I have already modified pagedlist to send it delegate to call after it fetches page with ajax call.

Comment: I am using jQuery datatable plugin and need to call it to format results. I don't know how to push it back to repo. maybe it will be useful for others.

Comment: I am  ruhnning into a similar issue, but I dont have @Html.Page... anything.  Is this only for mvc4?